# Tried using CTE on Hackerrank, it's not working, what could be the alternate solution?

Tags: mysql, common-table-expression

Just using this simple code to create CTE, in the end I want to create more complex code, that's why I am using CTE.

[Problem Link](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/interviews/problem?isFullScreen=true)

```
WITH TOTAL_SUBMISSIONS AS(
SELECT * FROM View_Stats)

SELECT * FROM TOTAL_SUBMISSIONS;
```

I get this Error

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TOTAL_SUBMISSIONS AS(
SELECT * FROM View_Stats)
SELECT * FROM TOTAL_SUBMISSIONS' at line 1
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return?

Answer (score 3):

Put the CTE into a subquery:

```
SELECT TOTAL_SUBMISSIONS.*
FROM (SELECT * FROM View_Stats) AS TOTAL_SUBMISSIONS
```

Comment: I know I can do that, just wanted to create CTE so that I further simplify my code.

Comment: But apparently HackerRank is using MySQL < 8.0, so it doesn't have CTE. I thought you were asking how to do it when CTE isn't available.

Comment: This answer made my day!!

Answer (score 3):

I encountered a similar situation where my CTE didn't work in HackerRank's MySQL environment. However, I have an interesting observation which is that if you switch from MySQL to MySQL server, then the CTE works, as indicated by the screenshot.

Note that the query provided by the op is not the final answer to the challenge. Rather it was used by the op to demonstrate the issue. So while the answer is Wrong, the result of the query is working in the MySQL Server environment.

This might not address the issue in the MySQL setting, but at least it allowed me to move forward with the code challenge.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hackerank is using MySQL version less than 8.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gAjLJ.png)

Your query could be update like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM View_Stats
) AS TOTAL_SUBMISSIONS;
```