# Why am I getting a syntax Error on hackerrank SQL problem using window functions (partition by)

Tags: mysql, syntax-error, window-functions

Hi I am trying to figure out why hackerrank is returning a syntax error on my query ran on their platform but when I run the same query I get no issues on mysql workbench.

Here is a snippet of the larger query I have written. I get an error 1064 (42000):

```
select  
lag(submission_date, 1,'2016-03-01') OVER(Partition by hacker_Id order by submission_date) 
from submissions ;
```

Comment: What does `SELECT VERSION();` return on their platform?

Comment: The complete error message will tell you exactly where the syntax error is, so post that. My guess is that you're using an older version of MySQL that doesn't support the window functions

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular here is the error message: ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 6: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(partition by hacker_Id) from submissions' at line 1

Comment: @BillKarwin  here is the output: 5.7.27-0ubuntu0.18.04.1

Comment: @BillKarwin I just looked it up. Version 5.7 does not support window functions. Thanks!

Comment: Window functions were added in 8.0.

Comment: Similar problem with CTE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72134462/tried-using-cte-on-hackerrank-its-not-working-what-could-be-the-alternate-sol

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.